# Installing BizTalk on Windows 7 with local accounts

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

In a Dev environment, I'm try to install BizTalk on windows 7 with local accounts.  The PC is not part of a domain.  The install goes fine, and I've followed the msdn documentation for BizTalk on windows 7.  SSO is the first thing that fails when I try and run the BizTalk configuration utility.

It created the SSODB database, built the tables, etc. but the SSO configuration failed.  I see errors in the event log like:

```
SSO AUDIT
 Function: GetApplications2
 Tracking ID: a9b83ad5-1f05-407f-9d0b-63b4e4acd7d5
 Client Computer: VM-BizTalk (mmc.exe:3572)
 Client User: VM-BizTalk\Jeremy
 Application Name: -
 Error Code: 0xC0002A02, The SSO system is currently disabled.

The SSO service is running under a local account. This is not recommended and will limit the functionality of SSO. See your documentation for details.
 SSO Service Account: VM-BizTalk

Access denied. The client user must be a member of one of the following accounts to perform this function.
 SSO Administrators: SSO Administrators
 SSO Affiliate Administrators: -
 Application Administrators: -
 Application Users: -
 Additional Data: VM-BizTalk\Jeremy 

Secret server access denied.
 Client User: VM-BizTalk\Jeremy
```

Both the sso service account and my account are part of the SSO administrators group (local accounts and groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did a little more digging, and found an additional error in the BizTalk Configuration log file:

**Failed to generate and backup the master secret to file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On\SSO0FAB.bak (SSO) Additional Information (0x80070005) Access is Denied.**

Searching this error I discovered a blog entry:

http://blogical.se/blogs/mikael_sand/archive/2009/10/01/failed-to-create-the-master-secret-file-why-do-these-things-always-happen-to-me.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Which advises this solution:

1. Unconfigure BizTalk and delete the SSODB and BusinessRulesDB. The wizard does not delete them.
2. Now create the SSO Administrators group manually and add the install account and the BizTalk Service Account to it.
3. Log out and log back in. Restart the installation.

I did the above steps.  Additionaly, after step 2 I re-ran the BizTalk install, chose repair, then went through the install process which took me though the configuration steps and finally a successful configuration!

Comment: Nice of you to share your findings