# BizTalk setup - issues with SSO configuration

Tags: sql-server, single-sign-on, biztalk

I'm having issues with SSO while installing BizTalk Server 2020 on my local dev machine. My machine is running windows 10 enterprise.

I have created a separate user for running BTS that I added to the local administrators group. I have also added the user in sql server with the sysadmin role.

The error says that the SSO service account must be a member of the SSO Administrators account on the SQL Server computer to access the SSO database. How can I solve this?

[image: Error message]

Comment: What OS is your local dev machine?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Found this error in the biztalk configuration log file:
***Failed to generate and backup the master secret to file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On\SSO0FAB.bak (SSO) Additional Information (0x80070005) Access is Denied***

Which lead me to this post and solution (creating the SSO Administrators group manually):
[Installing BizTalk on Windows 7 with local accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880247/installing-biztalk-on-windows-7-with-local-accounts)